# Screen recording for Android and ios

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I want to make it so that you can record a video in the application when you click a button, like in instagram. However, I have not found a working way to implement this.  Is there a plugin for recording video from the screen?I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Stackoverflow is english only!

Comment: TIL: There's also a russian SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it isn't even a question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a project for android or iOS and make the user be able to record his screen you could use a plugin that is working for unity. There is a tutorial [there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3zGzbe9V1o) and the plugin is free [here](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?v=j3zGzbe9V1o&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbU9BN1lkSHpHRml1WnktdlQ2cTlSZ3hiT191UXxBQ3Jtc0tsaTc3M2VEbm9oQXByRHhGcWZ1RkhXTTlUTXFXaGxFb3g3R0tVVm5ZcTdEdElRVHB5alhwSXdWZzBLQkJTNjRpSXZSMDFwSkJaWENiLXF2REZ5Qm5sdGp5NUtDcDRIdmpRdEhLcmtpMDRaOXlySExwRQ%3D%3D&event=video_description&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fthanh-nguyen-kim%2FUnity_Android_Screen_Recorder).
There are also some assets from the unity store such as

- **Everyplay**
- **Recorder**

You should try my first link, but even the other 2 can be valid